# How to construct a DAWG from a trie?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, trie, dawg

i just construct a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for a vocabulary, and then I found that there are many branches shared the same struct. i want to combine them together result to be a [DAWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_acyclic_finite_state_automaton).

What algorithm would I use to convert a trie to a DAWG?

Comment: @phs Directed acyclic word graph.

Comment: @user1540043 what have you already tried?

Comment: @maditya tried a vocabulary with almost 10k words, there are lots word shared the 'ing', 'er', ... suffix, and i just want to combine them, then the tried turned out to be a directed acyclic word graph.

Answer (score 5):

The standard algorithm for converting a trie into a DAWG works by treating the trie as a [deterministic finite automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton), then converting the trie into a [minimum-state DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization).

There are many algorithms for performing this conversion.  The algorithm I'm most familiar with is [Hopcroft's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization#Hopcroft.27s_algorithm), which works by finding pairs of distinguishable states and combining indistinguishable states together.

Hope this helps!